# Sort a datagrid column by an enum type

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, enums

I have a column in my `DataGrid` which displays some enumeration value.  I set the `SortMemberPath` to my property which is represented by these enumerated values.  However, when clicking on the column header, it won't sort on my enum because I haven't specified how to sort this type.  It's an enum, so I can't exactly override the < operator. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I'm trying to avoid a second property if I can.  I can only set SortMemberPath = "MyEnumProperty".  I can't tell it how to interpret that value.

```
_colDefs["Subtype"] = new DataGridTextColumn()
{       
    Binding = new Binding("") { Converter = new SubtypeConverter() },
    SortMemberPath = "Subtype"
};
```

My property looks like this:

```
public SubtypeEnum Subtype { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you show your xaml?

Comment: It should work out of the box. I agree with ethicallogics, some code would definitely help to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify property name in binding:

```
_colDefs["Subtype"] = new DataGridTextColumn()
{       
    Binding = new Binding("Subtype"),
    SortMemberPath = "Subtype"
};
```

You even won`t need converter anymore (if it just converts to string).

Answer (score 1):

You can cast an enum to int just by a hard cast:

```
(int)MyEnum.EnumValue
```

If you can add a fake property to your data structure that simply recasts its enumeration value to int, you ought to be able to sort it by that property, even if it's not visible.

Comment: Thanks Cody, a little out of it today.